# Solutions of $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&3\\ \end{pmatrix}x=0$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having a bit of confusion here.

What are the solutions of

$\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&3\\ \end{pmatrix}x=0$

Clearly,

$x_2=0$
$x_3=0$
$3x_3=0$

$x_1=s\in\mathbb{R}$, because there are no constraints for $x_1$.

then e.g.

$x=(1,0,0)$ is a solution.

But since this is from a matrix having double eigenvalue on this matrix, then shouldn't there be two solutions.

How do I formulate another solution?

Comment: An online eigenvalue and vector calculator claims that $x_2=(1,3,9)$ is another solution. But I don't see how it was discovered.

Comment: Is it for the same eigenvalue?

Comment: What matrix did you put in your online calculator? Because $(1,3,9)$ is an eigenvector of the matrix you give in your question, with eigenvalue $3$; so it must be an eigenvector of the original matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda+3$ (where $\lambda$ is your first eigenvalue).

Comment: So the calculator is this: http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/matrices-calculators/matrix-calculator.php and use matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0 \\ 0&1&1 \\ 0&0&4\\ \end{pmatrix}$, whose eigenvalues are 1 (two times) and 4 (one time).

Comment: Well, I get the same result, but it's just wrong. Try doing the product by hand and you will find that $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &1 \\ 0&0&4\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 3\\ 9\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 12 \\ 36\end{pmatrix},$ so the eigenvalue is $4$, not $1$.

Comment: I think the calculator has a bug. I did the eigenvector searching for eigenvalue $4$ by hand and this produces a solution $x=(1/9s,1/3s,s), s \in \mathbb{R}$. So it should report that the second one is for eigenvalue 4 and not 1.

Answer (score 4):

There is no other (independent) solution. $0$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix with *algebraic* multiplicity $2$, but the *geometric* multiplicity of $0$ (the dimension of the  kernel) is $1$..

Generally speaking, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$, we must distinguish between its algebraic multiplicity $m_\lambda$, i.e. its multiplicity as a root of the `characteristic polynomial`, and its geometric multiplicity, i.e. the dimension of $\ker(A-\lambda I)$. There is a relation between these numbers:
$$1\le \dim\ker(A-\lambda I)\le m_\lambda.$$
The matrix is `diagonalisable` if and only if `the geometric multiplicity and the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue are equal`. 
In particular, if all eigenvalues are simple, the matrix is diagonalisable.

This means here that your matrix will only have a Jordan normal form: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}.$$
One can calculate this happens in basis
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix},\enspace\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix},\enspace\begin{bmatrix}
1\\3\\9
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

> But since this is from a matrix having double eigenvalue on this matrix, then there should be two solutions.

If you mean that the characteristic polynomial has a double root, then this does not mean that you can find two linearly independant eigenvectors.

For a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then its *algebraic multiplicity* $\mu_A(\lambda)$ is defined as its multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial, and its *geometric multiplicity* $\gamma_A(\lambda)$ is defined as the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace. It can be proven that $\gamma_A(\lambda)\leq \mu_A(\lambda)$, but the inequality can be strict.

In your case there are no solutions other than $(1,0,0)$ (up to a constant), since the two last coordinates need to be $0$, as you noticed. So here $1=\gamma_A(\lambda)\neq \mu_A(\lambda)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many solutions $v = (t, 0, 0)$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The rank of the matrix is smaller than its row size.

Comment: I think the OP already has this solution.  The Question really asks why there are not two linearly independent solutions, since the eigenvalue zero appears twice on the diagonal (of the triangular matrix) and is a double root of the characteristic equation.  In other words, why is the *geometric* multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ less than its *algebraic* multiplicity.